# convert list of dict into list of list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary.

```
l = [{'row':1}, {'row':2}, {'row':1}, {'row':3}, {'row':1}]
```

I want output as :

```
x = [[{'row':1}, {'row':1}, {'row':1}], [{'row':2}], [{'row':3}]]
```

I want lists of those dicts whose 'row' value is same.
  How can I do that using python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> l = [{'row':1}, {'row':2}, {'row':1}, {'row':3}, {'row':1}]
>>> row = lambda d: d['row']
>>> [list(grp) for _, grp in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=row), key=row)]
[[{'row': 1}, {'row': 1}, {'row': 1}], [{'row': 2}], [{'row': 3}]]
```

**NOTE** You need to pass sorted list to `groupby`.

**Alternative** that does not require sorting, using [`collection.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> l = [{'row':1}, {'row':2}, {'row':1}, {'row':3}, {'row':1}]
>>> ret = defaultdict(list)
>>> for d in l:
...     ret[d['row']].append(d)
...
>>> ret.values() # list(d.values())   in Python 3.x
[[{'row': 1}, {'row': 1}, {'row': 1}], [{'row': 2}], [{'row': 3}]]
```

As shx2 commented, the alternative solution result will be arbitrary. If you want sorted result, use following form:

```
>>> [ret[key] for key in sorted(ret)]
[[{'row': 1}, {'row': 1}, {'row': 1}], [{'row': 2}], [{'row': 3}]]
```

Comment: The order is not guaranteed when using a defaultdict

Comment: @shx2, You're right. But groupby solution also does not guarantee original order.

Comment: what is list in defaultdict(list)?

Comment: @sam, `defaultdict` acts like a dictionary. except it create new element using callback (`list` in this case) when accessed with non-existing key. If you follow the link in the answer, you can find more detail.

Comment: what is the values are not numbers but string. like '1', '2' ets?

Comment: @sam, If they're all single-character string, it will just work. But if you  want sort them as number, you need to modify code slight. Instead of `d['row']` use `int(d['row'])`. (for both solution)

Comment: @shx2, Think about this case: `l = [{'row':1}, {'row':3}, {'row':1}, {'row':2}, {'row':1}]`

Comment: @falsetru since you first sort by `row` (which is presumably the order OP wants), you are guaranteed to have all the `1`s first, then all the `2`s etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
x_dict = {}
for d in l:
    x_dict[d['row']] = x_dict.get(d['row'], []) + [d]
x = [x_dict[key] for key in sorted(x_dict.keys())]
```